# How are overloaded functions selected for suitability in C++?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, overloading, optional-parameters

I need some help understanding how overloaded C++ functions are selected by the compiler.

When given a function:

```
type func(type1 x, type2 y);
type func(type3 x, type2 y);
```

How does the compiler determine which function to choose?

I know the function chosen is according to its suitability, but how to you know which function is chosen if either could be used successfully.

For example:

Given these function overloaded functions:

```
char* average(int i, float f, double d);
double average(double d, float f, int i);
double fabs(double d);
```

Given these variables:

```
int i1, i2, i3;
float f1, f2, f3;
```

What data type is the return value of these function calls? and why?

```
average(i1, i2, i3);
average(f1, f2, f3);
fabs(average(f1,f2,f3));
```

Comment: Well, you can find the answer to your specific examples by just running your code...

Comment: And for the long answer, you can look at that section of the standard that deals with type conversions and promotions and overload resolution. Being new to C++, I don't recommend it yet.

Comment: In your case, the compiler chooses between functions based on the name alone, because your functions have different names.

Comment: It's quite clear even in the question what the return types will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compile a function call, the compiler must first perform **name lookup**, which, for functions, may involve **[argument-dependent lookup(ADL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)**.
If these steps produce more than one candidate function, then **overload resolution** is performed to select the function that will actually be called.
In general, the candidate function whose parameters match the arguments most closely is the one that is called.

As in your case:

1--> `char* average(int i, float f, double d);`

2--> `double average(double d, float f, int i);`

Here in both of your functions you have completly different argument list. 1st average is taking `int`, `float`, `double` and the 2nd one is `double`, `float`, `int`.

So, compiler decides which method to invoke first based in its arguments.
If you invoke method with argument `(int, float, double)` the overloaded version takes 1st method and if you invoke method with argument `(double, float, int)` the overloaded version takes 2nd method.

The choice if which overloaded method to call(in other words, the signature of the method) is decided at compile time.
So, compiler will already know the signature of the method to be invoked.

While overloading methods we must keep the following rules in mind:

- Overloaded methods MUST change the argument list,
- Overloaded methods CAN change the return types.
- Overloaded methods CAN change the access modifier.
- A method can be overloaded in the same class or in a subclass.

Comment: Thank you, but according to what the arguments are changed ?
I mean, if I declare a function with (int, float, double), can I call it with (int, int, float) ? what are the rules for this implicit conversion ?

Comment: Its not up to you to call a function with what value you want. The conversions takes place according to rules defined.
As i explained to you above **candidate function whose parameters match the arguments most closely is the one that is called**

When you declare a function with argument list `(int, float, double)` , and in the call if you place the `(int, int, float)`, the compiler first checks for function defination which has arguments`(int, int, float)`and then if it doesnt find these arguments it goes for next best match i.e. `(int, float, double)` in your case doing implicit conversion.

Comment: I hope you understood something.

Comment: yes I understood, but one last thing, if I call (float, float, float), then according to my code I will get an error because the compiler will not to know what to choose (because both functions are in the same level of suitability) right ?

Comment: Wrong! When you call `(float, float, float)` none of your function will be suitable. As `int` cannot be converted implicitly. And `int` is present in both of your functions. So, It wont be possible match in both of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

The return value depends on the function call that is made. For example your first function call would return value double because second average function is called.

The function overloading solely takes place on basis of arguments irrespective of return types. You can't overload two functions solely on basis that they have different return types. The functions should differ by arguments in order for function overloading to work.